# Trying to find a way to revers a series of functions

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

Exploring some shader come I came up in front of that set of equations :

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i3mmcqw2rt

My math level not being that advanced i'm struggling.

I have a List of Values that give me C

And i'm trying to get , given a C value reverse the operation to get a B value
( so trying to get 2 inverts function to revert the calculations basically )

Is this possible ? and if yes , how can I do it ?

Thanks for your help !

Update :
Floor function are impossible to reverse due to loss of informations.

Comment: For the same $y$ you have many $x$. So you cannot get a function $B(C)$ cause there are a lot of values of $B$ to get the same $C$.

Comment: A(x) and B(A) are easy enought to invert, but C(B) is going to be impossible to invert due to the floor function

Comment: yeah that's what i thought ... 

Thanks for confirming 

i'm updateing the question with where I am at just for the sake of getting , even an approximation of the value